# Delete a record from tableB after receiving a unique constraint error from tableA

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, prepared-statement

I have the code below that first inserts a record in `tableA` -- and it successfully inserts a new record.

When I try to insert a duplicate record to get `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` (and it actually falls here), it should process my  delete `executeUpdate` but unfortunately gives me `"success = 0"`, it has not affected any row.

What am I missing? Thank you in advance!

```
  try  {
        session.save(tableA);
  }catch(SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException ex)  {
        log.debug("catch me im fallin");
        PreparedStatement ps;
        String sql= "DELETE FROM tableB WHERE id = " +id;

        try {
            con = wa.getSession().connection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            int success = ps.executeUpdate();
            log.debug("success : "+success);

        } catch (Exception e) {
             //
        }
  }catch(SQLException ex)  {
      //
  }
```

Comment: You got a constraint violation while inserting, so the record has *not* been inserted. Then, the `delete` deletes zero rows, which is to be expected. Anything I am missing?

Comment: How can you be sure that a row with the same `id` that failed for `Table A` exists in `Table B`. Maybe there is no such record, and so there `0` records deleted.

Comment: @giorgiga you're missing that the insert fails on `table a` but delete is performed on `table b`..

Comment: @Plirkee, I tried `select * from tableB where id = id_A` id_A is the id supposed to be inserted in tableA but as said, it failed resulting to fall in my catch block.

Comment: @AndI So, if I understand you correctly, when you execute `select` manually - you do find a corresponding row in `tableB`... Then the next question is what datatype is the `id` in your tables, also what data type is the `id` variable in your java code?